# How to control the naming of ELB made by Beanstalk in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating a beanstalk application that is also building an elb resource.

I cannot figure out how to choose what name that ELB resource has.  I cannot find it in the terraform documentation nor general options: "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbloadbalancer"

I want to choose the name which I thought a tag might do, but if there is one I cannot find good documentation for what tags can be used with Beanstalk.

Comment: why do you care of the elb name, you can define a Route 53 domain name on it to simplify the access.

Comment: I care because, I have traffic policies in place that need to querry for the created elb to pull its id.  If I cannot control the naming it gets tricky really quickly.